# PHP SQL Result Won't Populate a Profile Page

Tags: php, html, mysql, session, profile

I'm new to PHP and MySQL, and am having some trouble.
Essentially, a Musician's profile page is supposed to populate (Name, Picture, Genre, Bio, etc...) using a query with the Band's name as the search parameter.

A user is shown a list of band names (click-able links), and depending on which one they click, a value is passed and their info is displayed. However, the profile page is coming up empty!
Here is the Musician's name as a link in a table...

```
<form method="post" action="bandPageAll.php">
...
<?php                               
$i = 0;
while ($i < $num) {
    $GENRE = mysql_result($result,$i,"profile.PROFILE_GENRE");
    $BANDNAME = mysql_result($result,$i,"profile.PROFILE_BANDNAME");
?>                              
<tbody>
    <tr>
    <td><?php echo $GENRE; ?></td>
    <td><a href="bandPageAll.php" name="band"><?php echo $BANDNAME; ?></a></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
...
```

And here is the profile page's php code...

```
<?php
session_start();
foreach($_POST AS $key => $val) {
$_SESSION[$key]=$val;
}

mysql_connect("***", "***", "***");
mysql_select_db("***");

$bandname=$_POST['band'];
$bandname = stripslashes($bandname);
$bandname = mysql_real_escape_string($bandname);

$sql="SELECT * FROM profile WHERE PROFILE_BANDNAME='$bandname'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

$name = $row['PROFILE_BANDNAME'];
$genre = $row['PROFILE_GENRE'];
$bio = $row['PROFILE_BANDBIO'];
$bandpicture = $row['PROFILE_PICTURE'];
?>
```

....
Then html code.
And there are echoes throughout the profile page, echoing $name, $genre, $bio, and $bandpicture with styling, but that's not important. Aside from the nav bar I've coded, and the footer, the "body" of the page is showing up empty, and I have no idea why. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Try see with `echo $sql;` what query is sent to mysql, then, eventualy test that query in phpmyadmin

Comment: mysql_connect is deprecated see this : http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php

Comment: Tried this, and the result displayed was
SQL: SELECT * FROM profile WHERE PROFILE_BANDNAME=''

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to post data without a submit call. That won't send anything to your profile page. Try this instead:

```
<td><input type="submit" name="band" value="<?php echo $BANDNAME; ?>" /></td>
```

Try using print_r($row) after you call the mysql_fetch_assoc($result). That will print out all of the results from the SQL query.

EDIT: I forgot that mysql_fetch_array was deprecated. I edited my answer to reflect that.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.
First, i tried this...
    <td><input type="submit" name="band" value="
    <?php echo $BANDNAME; ?>" /></td>
but the table results weren't click-able, so I had to change it to...
    <td><a href="bandPageAll.php" type="submit" name="band">
    <?php echo $BANDNAME; ?></a></td>
Then used the print_r($row) on my profile page and changed to fetch_assoc, but it's still showing up empty, and nothing was printed as a result of print_r($row).

Comment: An anchor tag won't submit a form like that. You'd need to use Javascript instead. The reason your page is blank is because nothing is getting submitted. Instead of using POST, you should use GET. You can do <a href="bandPageAll.php?band=<?php echo $BANDNAME; ?>"><?php echo $BANDNAME; ?></a>. You can also get rid of the form tags. Then in your bandPageAll.php change $_POST to $_GET. As the others mentioned make sure you debug/echo your SQL statements to make sure they are correct.